# Cannot find the "Create Pose Asset" Button in Version 3.5.0

Tags: animation, pose-mode, asset-browser

I am looking for the "Create Pose Asset" button in the "Animation" side tab (as seen below in version 3.4.0).

[image: The Create Pose Asset Button as seen in Version 3.4.0]

As far as I was aware, this button was the "intended" way to create pose assets to be used on armatures. In fact, the user manual directly refers to this button:

> For preset assets, there will be a dedicated button for the different
> asset types. Currently poses are the only preset assets; use the
> Create Pose Asset button in the Action editor.

However, since updating to version 3.5.0, this button is now gone (as seen below).

[image: The same panel in Version 3.5.0; the button is missing.]

Instead, the "Create Pose Asset" option now appears to be located in the "Asset" dropdown menu of the Asset Browser, which is a bit more tedious to access (which accumulates to a substantial time loss over time when animating). This seems like a strange thing to remove, as it slows down the process of quickly saving poses for later use, so I would love to know whether this button is still accessible somewhere besides the Asset Browser's dropdown menu. Thank you!

Comment: Does the note below the description in [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/posing/editing/pose_library.html#pose-creation-via-action-editor) part of the Blender manual help?

Comment: Yep i have found the button but it's grayed out. Im trying to make asset pose from a armature.

Comment: @JohnEason That certainly works for me, thank you very much! I would still prefer to have the button in the viewport, since that's the main workspace I use at the point of the pipeline in which the pose library is most needed, but it's good to know it still exists. Thanks again.

Comment: I’m facing exactly the same issue. I can’t seem to find the “create pose asset” button. Is this a blender error or something. When I use the button in the dope sheet, it doesn’t change the poses even after registering them with the “create pose asset”. Any suggestions or solutions for this?

Comment: I have the same problem. So far I have found no fix.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the asset browser, on the top left there is a dropdown menu that might say *All*. You have to switch this to *Current File*. That worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the issue. This solution works if the button is greyed out, because Blender cannot write an asset to an "all" directory, but in my case, the button is not greyed out, it is missing entirely.

Comment: blender 4.0.2, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the button in the Dope Sheet, but it was also annoying for me to lost the button.

[image: dope sheet]

Comment: As I have just found out, this unfortunately does not work. This button creates a keyframe of the current pose and ONLY works as long as the armature has an active keyframe.
This leaves me with a pretty massive problem: I genuinely do not know how to save pose assets in the current Blender version. The fact that no one else seems to be talking about this issue makes me think I am missing something, but I am absolutely at a loss. This renders my usual workflow basically impossible and I have no idea what I am supposed to do now.